# I want to show project name & hours on chart js using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am a beginner at Laravel I am trying to show project name and hours on the chart.js. Unfortunately, data is not showing on the chart; how can I show that?

**controller**

**Chart script**

```
 <script>
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

    type: 'bar',
    @foreach($hour_logs   as  $key=>$value)
    data: {

        //labels: ['Red','Purple'],

          labels: {{$value}},

        datasets: [{
    
            data: {{$value}},
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', 
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', 
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    @endforeach
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

**return response**

```
[
  "Joylinkhk: 13,",
  "HorizonTechnologies: 2,",
  "Alahazrat: 9,",
  "j2w: 0,"
]
on the left side project name and on the right side hours 


dd($hour_logs)

array:4 [
  0 => "Joylinkhk: 13,"
  1 => "HorizonTechnologies: 2,"
  2 => "Alahazrat: 9,"
  3 => "j2w: 0,"
]
```

Comment: Is it possible write php code in javascript ??

Comment: yes it's possible

Comment: Please update your question with whatever dd($hour_logs) contains

Comment: dd($hour_logs)

array:4 [
  0 => "Joylinkhk: 13,"
  1 => "HorizonTechnologies: 2,"
  2 => "Alahazrat: 9,"
  3 => "j2w: 0,"
]

Comment: This is an odd way of doing things. I highly suggest to use `json_encode` instead of manually interpolating values.

Comment: @Zubair See this http://www.arrayconsortium.com/Covid19/covid-graph may be it is helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

When passing complex data structures from PHP to JavaScript you will most likely want to be converting them to JSON.

You can convert arrays to JSON using `json_encode()`. If you are using Larvel collections, they can be converted using `->toJson()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use Following code
You must send data from controller by parsing like this

```
implode(',', $label) and 
implode(',', $value)


<script>
let label = {!! $label !!}
let value = {!! $value !!}
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

type: 'bar',
@foreach($hour_logs   as  $key=>$value)
data: {

    //labels: ['Red','Purple'],

      labels: label.split(','),

    datasets: [{

        data: value.aplit(,),
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)', 
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)', 
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
@endforeach
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero: true
            }
        }]
    }
}
});
</script>
```